# jQuery Dual slider moving at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

Can anyone provide some insight on how I would be able to count the two slider ranges to act as one? If max range is 100 and user moves slider 1 to 30 then slider 2 should move to 70. The total value would always be what the range is. setting up the same `class` for both I assume will be needed, but I know its a lot more than that.

my setup http://testzone.me/ia/price.html

this is the jquery slider http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/

```
<input type="text" data-slider="true" value="0.8" data-slider-range="01,100" data-slider-step="0.2" data-slider-highlight="true">
<input type="text" data-slider="true" value="0.8" data-slider-range="01,100" data-slider-step="0.2" data-slider-highlight="true">


  <script>
  $("[data-slider]")
    .each(function () {
      var input = $(this);
      $("<span>")
        .addClass("output")
        .insertAfter($(this));
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
      $(this)
        .nextAll(".output:first")
          .html(data.value.toFixed(2));
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
<input id="slider-2" type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1,99">
<input id="slider-1" type="text" value="99" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1,99">


var total = 100;

$("#slider-1").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
      $('#slider-2').simpleSlider("setValue", total - data.value);
    console.log(event);
});

$("#slider-2").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
      $('#slider-1').simpleSlider("setValue", total - data.value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/Vpr4w/)